# Replacing value in list

Tags: python

I've got the following list, which is stored in a variable called 'mylist'.

mylist = (('', 'Select Square Feet'), ('100', '100 Square Feet'), ('200', '200 Square Feet'))

How would I change 'Select Square Feet' to be 'Select' using python?

Thanks!

Comment: That’s the syntax for a tuple. Is it actually a tuple?

Comment: @Jason Howard I think you are little confused with lists, tuples and so. I would recommend to once again go and check them from where you learnt Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't a list. It's a tuple. Tuples are immutable and can't be changed. It is also a tuple of tuples so the inner tuples must also be lists if you want to change one of their elements. Tuples are created with parentheses (actually the parentheses are optional its the comma that really does it) use brackets:

`mylist = [['', 'Select Square Feet'], ['100', '100 Square Feet'], ['200', '200 Square Feet']]`

Now with this the way you would change `'Select Square Feet'` to `'Select'` is by using indexing:

`mylist[0][1] = 'Select'`

Here the `0` refers to the first element of the outer list and the `1` refers to the second element of the inner list.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a tuple, which cannot be changed after defining it. These types of data structures are called immutable.

Instead, replace it with a list:

```
# Define a list using square brackets []
mylist = [['', 'Select Square Feet'], ['100', '100 Square Feet'], ['200', '200 Square Feet']] 

# Access list elements using indices
print(mylist[1][1]) # prints 100 square feet

# Modify the list elements using indices
mylist[0][1] = 'Select'
```